# Websphere application server (network deployment) for windows server 2012

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am planning to install websphere application server on Windows server 2012. As per IBM documents it is compatible with it.

I am looking for the installer of WAS-ND 8.0. And I found this :

IBM part number :CZM9KML, ..
I found this part number from below site :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021166#windows

But on IBM software access catalog, I come to know that it is compatible with :

*Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Professional, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows Server 2008 Standard Ed, Windows Vista Business, Windows Vista Enterprise, Windows Vista Ultimate* 
But  windows server 2012 is not there.

I want similar WAS-ND installer for windows server 2012. Can anyone have part number or link for that particulars?

Comment: Try to install, it will work!

Comment: @Yash, Thanks,  It will be great if you can provide me any link to clarify that or have  you experienced the same?

Comment: See this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021166#windows, You can find that WAS is supported Microsoft Windows x86-32 and 64 bit architectures. And I think, windows server 2012 (Server version of windows 8) is x86-64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment (WAS-ND) 8.0 *is* compatible with Windows Server 2012, but only from version 8.0.0.5.

Here is a screenshot from the [Software Product Compatibility Reports page](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=2083A2F084D011E5B8E08EB2D60FE72C&osPlatforms=Windows&duComponentIds=S001|S002|S003|S004&mandatoryCapIds=25&optionalCapIds=341|9|13|39|8|20|26|40):

[image: SPCR Screenshot]

The fifth column is the minimum maintenance level required for the product to run on the system, which is 8.0.0.5.

So, install the base package (v8.0) and then install [Fix Pack 5](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033754) before you create any server profiles. You should be able to work with WAS profiles once you are at v8.0.0.5.

Do note that only the WAS-ND component is supported on Windows Server 2012. The Edge Components (Caching Proxy & Load Balancer) are not supported on this OS.

Comment: yes I know that, What I was looking for is instalers.

Comment: Correction : *installers

Comment: There are no separate installers for Server 2012. The same eAssembly parts in your question (CZM9KML/CZM9LML/CZM9MML/CZVG4ML) will work for all supported Windows Installations.